# Android Documentation List View Example Source Code In XML

Tags: java, android, layout

If you look at the Android documentation about how to [implement a List View and populate it](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-listview.html) you will notice that they only teach you how to do it in Java extending `ListActivity` instead of the normal `Activity`, but how would the same code (layout and populate the list) using XML layout files and extending `Activity`?

I'm asking this because I want to implement a `RelativeLayout` and add more elements to the screen where the `ListView` is with more flexibility than using `.inflate()` and `addHeaderView()`/`addFooterView()`.

Answer (score 8):

I think the way you are looking is creating and populating your own list.

- create a main layout (mainLayout.xml) // It should have a linear layout at least one.
- create a template layout for your list rows.
- In your activity inflate your template in for loop, populate it and append it to your main layout.

here is an example,

**listtemplate.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:id="@+id/listLayout"
    android:clickable="true"
    >
            <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
                      android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" 
                      android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
                      android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                      android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                      android:layout_alignParentTop ="true"
                      android:id="@+id/mainText" 
                      android:text="TextView">
                </TextView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

and in your activity,

```
public void CreateAndAppendListLayout() 
{
   List<String> mainList; //populate it...
   LinearLayout mainLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.mainLayout);
   LayoutInflater li =  (LayoutInflater)getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
   for (int i = 0; i < mainList.size();  i++){
       View tempView = li.inflate(R.layout.listtemplate, null);
       TextView textMain = (TextView) tempView.findViewById(R.id.mainText);

       textMain.setText(mainList.get(i)); 
       mainLayout.addView(tempView);
      } 
}
```

Comment: But that doesn't use a `ListView`

Answer (score 1):

You can extend from Activity with no problems. Extending from ListActivity just helps you by doing most of the (very easy) legwork. You can [see the source code](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.0.3_r1/android/app/ListActivity.java#ListActivity) to understand what it does. It boils down to calling findViewById() and setting the adapter. The hardest part about dealing with ListViews are the Adapters, not the ListViews themselves.