# Repeat a layout at run time in android

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I have a xml file and i want to repeat a RelativeLayout portion programmatically in my code. How can i repeat the layout at run time?.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="0.11" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="39dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="26dp"
        android:text="Button" />

</RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Repeat? what do you mean? adding more same RelativeLayout on runtime?

Comment: yes i want to add n number of same layout at run time.

Comment: looks like you're reinventing the wheel (ListView) ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9106698/603127) you can find my answer about creating and populating a layout list on runtime.

Answer (score 2):

```
LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater) currentContext
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            v = vi.inflate(R.layout.id, null);
parentview.add(v);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [LayoutInflater](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/LayoutInflater.html) to instantiate XML layouts multiple times.

```
LayoutInflater  inflater = (LayoutInflater)getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
View view = (View) inflater.inflate(R.layout.yourxml, null);
```

Comment: any example or tutorial will be appreciative. i have been stuck here for 1 day. i am also new in android.

Comment: Thanks a lot actually i have been using the search engine but approach were different.